# mono in unity 3d and .net remoting

Tags: c#, mono, unity-game-engine, remoting

I am working on a Unity project where I need to work with a remoting client. I have created an interface class and I am using a remoting server in an other Unity project.

While the server is working without problems, the creation of the client fails with following exception:

> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketCache ---> System.NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented.
>     at System.Threading.ThreadPool.UnsafeRegisterWaitForSingleObject (System.Threading.WaitHandle waitObject, System.Threading.WaitOrTimerCallback callBack, System.Object state, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean executeOnlyOnce) [0x00000] in :0

My code for the client:

```
MyRemotableObject remoteObject;

void Awake ()
{
    try
    {
        TcpChannel chan = new TcpChannel();
        ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(chan, false);
        remoteObject = (MyRemotableObject)Activator.GetObject(typeof(MyRemotableObject), "tcp://localhost:124/TargetShooterMenu");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogError(e.ToString());
    }
....
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
According to [Mono FAQ](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ%3a_Technical), Mono should have remoting support.
I am workin with Unity 3.5.1 (should have Mono 2.6.3) on a Windows 7 x64 Professional machine.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the server also Mono-based or is it .NET?

Comment: It is also Mono-based (aka a Unity Program), but the server works

Comment: Have you installed the appropriate libmono-system-runtimeX.Y-cil package for your distribution (X.Y being a version number. 2.0, 4.0, etc)

Comment: I have MonoDevelop Version 2.8.2.
As Mono was installed with Unity Editor 3.5 I don't know exactly where to search.

Comment: What's your OS? If Linux, which flavor?

Comment: Win 7 Professional x64
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/232756/what-is-the-current-version-of-mono-in-unity-35.html
Mono should be 2.6.3

Comment: I am implementing the same thing in my project. Inter Process Communication. I will be doing TCP communications and serializing objects back and forth with json. Let me know if you were able to implement this on your project as I just determined that Unity Mono does not fully support remoting.

Comment: I have gotten .net Remoting working with my Unity Project. On mac no less. :) Ill post an answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Unity to do the exact same thing.

First thing you have to do is change the player Api Compatibility Level from ".Net 2.0 subset" to ".Net 2.0"

Next you have to get the 2.0 mono library "System.Runtime.Remoting.dll" from MonoDevelop

Mine was located at "/Applications/Unity/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Libraries/mono/2.0/System.Runtime.Remoting.dll"

place that into the "Assets/Plugins" folder and Unity will take care of dragging out the rest of the libraries.

From then on out, it seems that remoting works without a hitch :)

If you add the Remoting dll and build only to find an error like "But the dll is not allowed to be included or could not be found" then your still using ".Net 2.0 Subset"

Answer (score 0):

There are two options here:

1. The used .NET subset does not support it. Switch between the 2.0 subset and full 2.0 in the player settings and test again
2. If that does not help then I fear you can not do anything about it aside of either implementing an own protocol or going true native code using DLLImport. The problem here is the unsafe code reliance which in Unity normally is disabled and cut from its custom Mono version (which bases on Mono 2.6).
   Unity does neither support nor use the systems Mono version, so any tests and assumptions basing on those are irrelevant in this situation.

Comment: To point one -> I have already switched to 2.0, no success
To point two -> That will be a challenge ^^
What i want to accomplish is basically to be able to send int data from a application to an other (both unity)
In case you have another solution for that case, let me know...